# SQL THREE TABLE QUERY FORMATION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

```
table a             table b                        table c
+--------+          ---------+-------            ------+-------+
| ID     |              ID  | STATUS|             ID  | STATUS|
+--------+         ---------+--------            -----+--------+
| 1      |              4   |  A    |              6  | A
| 2      |              5   | NULL  |              5  |NULL
| 3      |              1   | A     |              3  | A
| 9      |              2   | NULL  |              1  | NULL
```

Now I want a record from TABLE B and C which matches TABLE A ID

I wrote an query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM
  (SELECT a.ID,b.STATUS FROM A a B b where a.ID=b.ID
   UNION
   SELECT a.ID,C.STATUS 
   FROM A a,C C 
   WHERE a.ID=C.ID) as T
```

it returns 3 records

but when I append where condition T.STATUS='A'

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM
  (SELECT a.ID,b.STATUS FROM A a B b
   WHERE a.ID=b.ID
   UNION
   SELECT a.ID,C.STATUS 
   FROM A a,C C 
   WHERE a.ID=C.ID) as T 
WHERE T.STATUS='A'
```

it returns 2 records

again I changed WHERE condition as T.STATUS is null

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM
 (SELECT a.ID,b.STATUS 
  FROM A a,B b
  WHERE a.ID=b.ID
  UNION 
  SELECT a.ID,C.STATUS
  FROM A a,C C
  WHERE a.ID=C.ID) as T
WHERE T.STATUS is null
```

it returns 2 records

totally 4 RECORDS but my first query without where condition it returns 3

How this mismatch? I know its my query problem but

I want to apply my where condition to only 3 records(query without where condition returns result).

Comment: Try to avoid comma seperated JOINS!

Comment: This can't be the SQL you're using.  Two from statements on the 2nd union select?

Answer (score 4):

You are selecting `distinct id`.  `id = 1` has rows with both 'A' and `NULL`.  The results make sense.

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM (SELECT a.ID, b.STATUS
      FROM A a JOIN
           B b 
           ON a.ID=b.ID 
      UNION
      SELECT a.ID, C.STATUS
      FROM A a JOIN
           C C 
      WHERE a.ID = C.ID
     ) T
```

Note that your original query had at least one syntax error.  You should learn proper explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: I was about to write the same! +1

Comment: Yes result make sense ,but i want to apply where condition to 3 records because i don't want to apply the where condition to duplicates of ID